# How to encode to FLAC using QtAV?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use [QtAV](http://www.qtav.org) in C++ (gcc g++ 5.4.0 on modern GNU/Linux) with Qt 5.6.2, to encode Linear PCM data to FLAC.

My **input** data consists of linear PCM samples, signed 16-bit little endian, 48 kHz sample rate, and variously either 1 or 2 channels. I have the input data stored in a `QByteArray`.

My **output** data needs to be a FLAC format file (not Ogg/FLAC) with 16 kHz sample rate, **1 channel** (even if the input was 2 channels), and signed 16-bit little endian sample format. The output needs to be written to a `QByteArray` to be later used by the program. At no point do I want to interact with the filesystem because the data is being used on the fly by the application.

I have been looking through the very poor documentation and the source code (headers and .cpp files) [here](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/examples/audiopipeline/main.cpp) (and [here](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/QtAV/AVTranscoder.h), plus other headers and implementation for AVPlayer) and this is what I have so far:

```cc
QByteArray convert::convertRawToFlac(QByteArray data)
{
    QBuffer buf(data);
    QByteArray retval;
    QBuffer retbuf(&retval);
    AVTranscoder avt;
    AVPlayer player;
    QVariantHash muxopt, avfopt;

    player.setIODevice(buf);
    player.audio()->setBackends(QStringList() << QString::fromLatin1("null"));

    avt.setMediaSource(&player);
    avt.setOutputMedia(&retbuf);

    //Now need to set options (?) to specify the output codec and 
    //the input and output sample formats
}
```

It's not clear to me how to proceed from here. My main sticking point is understanding how to tell QtAV (1) what my input format is; (2) to not do anything related to video (this is purely audio); (3) what my desired output format is (use FLAC encoder) and the desired sample format (s16le, mono, 16 kHz).

Perhaps I'll have to convert the PCM data to the desired sample format before passing it to the FLAC encoder? I'm not even sure.

Comment: `AudioEncoder* audioEncoder() const` which leads to `void setAudioFormat(const AudioFormat& format);` which leads to https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/QtAV/AudioFormat.h should answer half of (3).

Comment: Also notice that `AudioEncoder` is a subclass of [`AVEncoder`](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/QtAV/AVEncoder.h), which has `void setCodecName(const QString& name);`